# convert a cached item to a specific object type for return by webmethod

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, caching

I have successfully cached a large data item in a web service, but if I want to return that cached item later rather than running the lengthy query again, how can I convert the generic cached item to an object of my own design?

eg

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("cItem", [MyItem]));
```

then

```
return HttpContext.Current.Cache["cItem"];
```

will show an error in Visual Studio as I can't convert type 'object' to my own type.
Any pointer appreciated
thanks

Comment: You should post at least function signature but _maybe_ a cast is what you need...

Comment: if your signature is returning a `string` the you need to cast the return as `(string)HttpContext.Current.Cache["cItem"]` but can't determine without seeing the actual Method Signature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Cache[string]` returns an `object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.item%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  And while any instance of `MyItem` can be implicitly converted to an `object`, the reverse is clearly not true.

So if your method's return type is `MyItem` then you'd need to cast the cached item:

```
public MyItem MyMethod()
{
    return (MyItem)HttpContext.Current.Cache["cItem"];
}
```

This is done when retrieving from the cache, not when storing in it.

If there's a possibility that the item *isn't* of the expected type, you'd have to handle that condition somehow.  The code above will throw an `InvalidCastException` if that happens.  If you'd rather just return `null` in that case, you might try this instead:

```
public MyItem MyMethod()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Cache["cItem"] as MyItem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// if its a string etc.
return (string)HttpContext.Current.Cache["cItem"]; 

// if its a List of a custom object 
return (List<CustomObject>)HttpContext.Current.Cache["cItem"];
```